# Compile Commentscript

Tags: code-golf, string, javascript

Commentscript is a variant on Javascript that I made up for the purpose of this question. Only commented-out code is evaluated.

Javascript has two types of comments:

```javascript
// this is a single line comment, which starts with `//` and ends on a newline.

/*
This is a multiline comment.
It starts with /* and ends with */
```

Example:

```
//console.log('goodbye world')
console.log('hello world')
```

will output `goodbye world` to the console.

Your challenge is to compile Commentscript code into regular Javascript.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest bytes wins!

### Clarifications

Nested comments like `// comment // nested comment` should just have the top-level comment removed, for example `comment // nested comment`.

To avoid complications, comments in strings should be read as comments, e.g. `'abc //' def //ghi` => `' def //ghi`

Newlines from single line comments should be kept, but ones by multiline comments shouldn't.

Ignore shebangs, e.g. `#! /usr/bin/env node`

```
//a
//b
=>
a
b


/*a*/


/*b*/
=>
ab
```

### Test cases

```
//console.log('hello world') => console.log('hello world')

//console.log('hello world')//do stuff => console.log('hello world')//do stuff

/*var a = 5;*/function f(){}/*console.log(a)*/ => var a = 5; console.log(a)

/////////// => /////////

//console.log('hello world')/*More nested comments*/ => console.log('hello world')/*More nested comments*/

"abc //" def //ghi => " def //ghi

//a
//b
=>
a
b

/*a*//*b*/ => ab

//a



//b

//c
=>
a
b
c

/*
for(var x of array){
    console.log(x)
}
*/
=> 
for(var x of array){
    console.log(x)
}


/*
//this is a comment
*/

=>

//this is a comment


#!/usr/bin/env node =>  [NOTHING]
```

Comment: Sorry, adding testcase.

Comment: "To avoid complications, comments in strings should be read as comments," doesn't sound right. Are you sure? I'd say that comments cannot appear in strings. Otherwise this is solvable with boringly simple regex.

Comment: Is it allowed to comment out the code that isn't commented out, instead of removing it?

Comment: I think the above questions are a good indicator that this question could use some time in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first.

Comment: @Etheryte It was in the sandbox [during about 1 month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20797/58563). So I'd say that the above questions are a good indicator that the sandbox doesn't work very well.

Comment: I'd say that neither is the case (or rather, the questions above do not indicate either); almost all challenges - sandboxed or not - have some clarifications in the comments, and a fair number of them are simplified beyond what the challenge author, or anyone who saw the challenge in the Sandbox, notified or intended

Comment: What about `//` comments nested in `/**/` comments? should they remain commented or not? And the other way round? Also what is the goal of remplacing multiple newlines by a single one? This rule doesn't seem to add anything interesting to the challenge IMO

Comment: Can we ask for a trailing newline in the input?

Comment: @Adám it was discussed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/20797#comment71548_20797). The choice was between a simple challenge (solvable with regex), or a full javascript lexer including backslash escapes, string interpolation, and regex literals, which is not easy to specify or implement.

Comment: @Kaddath Sorry, forgot to specify that testcase. Will add.

Comment: @xigoi Wouldn't that make it harder?

Comment: @Kaddath Also, you're right, the newline compression is a problem. I'll fix that now, but newlines at the end of `//` comments should be kept.

Comment: For the test case `//console.log('hello world')/*More nested comments*/`, is the added space between `console.log('hello world')` and `/*More nested comments*/` correct? Also, are two multiline comments separated by non-newlines treated differently from two without (e.g. does `/*a*//*b*/` => `ab` (case 8) but `/*a*/text/*b*/` => `a b` (case 3), or are they the same?)

Comment: @Ausername I don't know, maybe it will be easier with some approaches. I thought about things like swapping `/*` and `*/` (which has its problems, but someone could refine it.)

Comment: @ErikF Sorry, typo. They're the same.

Comment: Consider a more complex javascript source file with comments [like this](https://tio.run/##bY29DoIwFIV3nuISTQpq7QP4M@iiu4kjICDWlHtNW2AgPDu2ukhicqZzvi/nmbWZybV8WY5UlOM4C0VjtLhJFL4I2kxDlhirJVawg3QDQsC8vzeYW0kIUQx9ACAWwsXD9iFN4oJkk5zqukTrPDYwTwnICQ2pcq2oitJTqRSl8df/XdiKxa5ywzbkfCKxK2lVMC/9u@J8P8XDD@rrZSexoG59aOzFmWdz/DrBMKTj@AY), what should the program output?

Comment: @tsh [This](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fpTqtNC@5JDM/T0FDU6GaS1@fSyE5P684PydVLyc/XSPBIzUnJz9Bk0sfWVRdR11T//9/AA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online"). Forgot about shebangs though, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 63 bytes

```
(//.*|/\*(.|¶)*?\*/|¶)|.
$1
//(.*)|/\*((.|¶)*?)\*/|(¶)¶*
$1$2$4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BTsMwEEX3PsVQItWehUcgWCHECbhBN05iN5FSj2Q7pajptXqAXizYgaKuYGTLI78/f36wqfdmniWRxok2KPV0OSt82yCVZtKiehBEUqNa8JWrIpC5vZwxS6rH6mmeiRr2kQerB97KdWeHgeGDw9CulRB/UaKWIabRuazDvQlg4BWeX5Dc6JvUswcn1fFEeOthFFLx/a1/luA7BwvexmRbaHi3sz7FYrEydQNEK2ity@@264uTybcueQwSYf29ywghfv6pKVA4DrIkPgA7MCGYT3UUkOs2yUGJk1gcMA@mro@Qj7mmWND9HY0xUN17sn4Pnlv7BQ) Link includes test cases, but the newline-collapsing rule means that they're not double-separated on output. Explanation:

```
(//.*|/\*(.|¶)*?\*/|¶)|.
$1
```

Delete anything not a newline or comment.

```
//(.*)|/\*((.|¶)*?)\*/|(¶)¶*
$1$2$4
```

Keep the content of comments and one newline of consecutive newlines.

Comment: Nice job! We'll have to see what others get up to!